# Force UniversalImageLoader DiskCache to clear files after changing configuration

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

During run of my app i have to reinit my ImageLoader and i do it like this:

```
if(ImageLoader.getInstance().isInited()) {
  ImageLoader.getInstance().destroy();
}

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(createConfig(context));
ImageLoader.getInstance().clearMemoryCache();
```

In my new `ImageLoaderConfiguration` i have to change cache size using `ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder.diskCacheSize(cacheSize)` method. Let's say that i have data that exceeds new limit. How to force ImageLoader to remove redundant data from cache? I didn't find any proper API, so i guess it has to be some sort of hack. Thanks in advance.